# What kind of date format is "401769" and how can I get this formatted like a real date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, content-management-system

What kind of date format is this and how can I get this formatted like a real date?

```
Expiredate="401769" 

Effectivedate="0" ModifiedWhen="39316.262472303242" CreatedWhen="38476.390116666669"
```

This is from Microsoft Content Management Server (MCMS) 2002 .sdo file (XML file exporting data)

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you could tell us which dates these values represent.

Comment: Read about [ToOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx) and [FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.FromOADate(39316.262472303242)` should get you the DateTime //gives  22/08/2007